# Wayfinder - create submenu item of parent under parent resource

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have parent resource 1 and parent resource 2.
I would like to use Wayfinder to create parent 2 as a submenu of parent 1.
I know how to create a submenu from children under a parent. But not from one parent under another parent. Is that even possible how?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a [Weblink](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/weblink) linking to parent 2 and position it as a child of parent 1

Comment: Ah...I guess you could always make a JS redirect chunk for that page that would do the same thing.

Or, you could use Ditto to duplicate the info from Resource 1 onto a child page. Probably not a good idea though, specially for SEO